# Website is blocking me accesing from Tor?

Tags: web, proxy, firewall, cloudflare, tor

i am trying to use webs, but when i am joinging from tor i am reciving this error 
"
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Request blocked.

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: (some id)
"
What can i do for avoid this error? a example webb would be www.mercadolibre.com i think cloudflare is blocking it, how to prevent

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that cloudfront has a tendency to block Tor exit nodes as cloud front sees Tor as an attack vector. This is relatively common and not much you can do about it besides to find an obscure or relatively new exit node.